# android解像度最適化

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

unityでUGUIを使ってandroidアプリを作成しています

主にUIデザインについて

・androidには様々な端末があるので、解像度、アスペクト比を考慮すると
全ての端末に合わせて作成するべきか、もしくは利用率の高い端末を優先するべきか

・例えばandroidの端末が5:3 800x480 なら　最適なアスペクト比、解像度はいくらか

・また、unityでgameviewを800x480と設定しても using resolutionとでて800x480とは
違う数字になるが、解像度には影響があるか

Answer (score 3):

> ・また、unityでgameviewを800x480と設定しても using resolutionとでて800x480とは
>   違う数字になるが、解像度には影響があるか

using resolution は、GameViewを縮小表示してるときに実際に表示してる大きさが出てるだけです。サイズを 800x480と設定しているのであれば実際は 800x480で処理されてるので解像度には影響ありません。

> ・例えばandroidの端末が5:3 800x480 なら　最適なアスペクト比、解像度はいくらか

Androidの解像度最適化については、ゲームやアプリごとに最適な方法が違ってくるので、一概に「この方法が最適である」というのは存在しないと思っています。

なので、方法は決めてしまって、それに対する質問をしたら良いかと思います。

・5:3 アスペクト比を維持したまま端末の画面にできるだけ大きく表示したい
・画面解像度を 800x480 基準に作成して、android実機に拡大表示したい
・UIパーツの解像度は固定で、どの端末の解像度にも適切に配置したい

Comment: androidの複数端末対応について、サイトなどを調べた結果　

・androidのpxサイズを作るときは、xxhdpiを基準にする（mdpiなら3分の1）
・UIの位置を固定するには、アンカーを使う

と書いてあったのですが、これが対応策でしょうか

質問としては、
・UIパーツの解像度は固定で、どの端末の解像度にも適切に配置したい　
です。

Comment: アンカーを使ってレイアウトするのが良さそうです。Unityサイトは情報の宝庫なので、この辺りからアンカーや画面への配置について調べると分かりやすいと思います。画面サイズが変わったときにどのように見た目がかわるか、アンカーで指定する方法とかが詳しく書いてあります。
http://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html

Comment: アンカーの位置を指定する方法はアンカープリセットで左上や中央などといった 指定のみですか？

Comment: http://www.metalbrage.com/UnityTutorials/uGUI/Scaler.htmlここを参考にして
canvasのscalewithScreenSizeで(x720y1280)expandに設定したのですが
540x960のandroid端末でunityremote4で確認してみたところUIはぶれていました。

Comment: 正直まだ目標とするところが見えてきません。複数の端末（解像度）で「こう配置されて欲しい」というのを数パターン（解像度バリエーション）を図に示してみてください。例えば、540x960の端末ならこう配置されて、720x1280の端末ではこう配置されるようにしたい、とか。

Comment: もしくは、他のゲームなりアプリを示して、これと同じようにしたいとかあれば。

Comment: 開発するのはandroidですが、例はiosです　
こういう感じにしたいです
http://appget.com/appli/view/65525

Comment: 「もしくは、他のゲームなりアプリを示して、これと同じようにしたいとかあれば。」と言っておきながら申し訳ないですが、やっぱり多機種での画面ショットがないと分からないので、例のアプリでもいいので複数端末でスクショ撮ってアップして「このパーツのように」とできるだけ具体的に示していただけると助かります。